# Cross Validation (sklearn train test split) - ValueError: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python

I have written this code and getting error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X0 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/Dataset for Experiment - 2019/ANFIS modeling data/china_data.csv')
train_test_split. X0 = X0.drop(columns = ['EFFORT'], axis = 1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X0, test_size=0.8)
```

The error which is showing for this code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X0, test_size=0.8)
```

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

I tried many times to remove this error but it is still persistent. Can anybody explain to me why I am getting this error & how can I remove this error?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You would have been able to solve this problem yourself by looking at the docs. Please choose a instructive title for your question next time, so that people can immediately understand what the topic/problem is.

Comment: definitely peter, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn expects to get `X` and `y` in `train_test_split()`.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

You only parse `X`.

See the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: thank you Peter, but can you tell me why random_state=42?

Comment: random state (aka seed) makes it possible to reproduce the split, read the docs